# use of template in another function

Tags: symfony

I have created a function file name as

```
<?php

use Ens\NewBundle\Controller\Services\MyMailers as MyMailers;

    function NotificationOnSignUp($z)
    {
        $x=new MyMailers;
    $x->setToloc($z['to']);
    $x->setFromloc('ucerturohit@gmail.com');
    $x->setSubject('Wonderful world');
    $x->setBody('Hello world');

    $z=$x->mail();
      if($z==1)
       $name='success';
      else
       $name='failed';

        return $this->render('EnsNewBundle:Email:ind.html.twig',array('name'=>$name));
//   return $z;  

}
```

this file is not in the controller but I want to render my twig file in this file or I want to set this twig file as Body of the mail. how can i do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create [a service](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html), inject the `templating` service into it and use it to render the template.

Comment: i dont want to use any service

Comment: I am creating my own service and I dont want to use in-built service then it doesnt mean that I should not use symfony? I can do work without services also?

Comment: I am asking this because I want to set this file only as the body of the mail

Comment: Like I said, make your service dependent on the `templating` service and use it to render a template.